# How do i make a basic decrypter in c++?

Tags: c++, encryption

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        char v = 'a';
        char a = 'b';
        char d = 'c';
        char p = 'd';
        char r = 'e';
        char s = 'f';
        char z = 'g';
        char t = 'h';
        char m = 'i';
        char i = 'j';
        char k = 'k';
        char o = 'l';
        char h = 'm';
        char e = 'n';
        char l = 'o';
        char b = 'p';
        char y = 'q';
        char g = 'r';
        char x = 's';
        char c = 't';
        char j = 'u';
        char w = 'v';
        char q = 'w';
        char n = 'x';
        char f = 'y';
        char u = 'z';
    }
    {
        char aa;
        cin >> aa;
        cout << "you input " << aa << endl;
        cout << "aa" << endl;
    }
    {
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

the aa part is what doesn't work, I need to be able to input a series of letters, and output the decryption of those letters.

this is what I have so far, but it's not working. I have the decrypter made I just don't have a way to tell it what t decrypt. I'm very new to c++, all help is very appreciated.

Comment: Why do you declare a bunch of local variables that then immediately go out of scope? What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: I don't like how the proposed answer has to do a find.  That chews up CPU time.